# The distance to last scattering surface incerease?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

The cosmic background radiation was released 38 million years after the Big Bang and is observed as the last scanning surface.
How does the distance to the last scattering surface differ when the observation time is present and in the past?
Please explain the distance change using the past light cone and world line picture.

Comment: Are you sure it was 38 million years?

Comment: https://www.space.com/33892-cosmic-microwave-background.html says it was about 400,000 years after the big bang.